# Alexa skill creation - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when live, but test works fine

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jackson, alexa-skills-kit

When I run my code on the AWS Lambda server I get this showing up
https://gyazo.com/7b26f2af77451117cea8ab38f52fcbde
Its an error obviously, stack trace being

```
{
"errorMessage": 
"com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase.findFormatOverrides(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanProperty;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat$Value;",
"errorType": "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError",
"stackTrace": [
"com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase.createContextual(JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase.java:34)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDeserializer.createContextual(InstantDeserializer.java:235)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleSecondaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:669)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:430)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.findDeserializer(StdDeserializer.java:947)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:439)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:296)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:428)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:179)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:108)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:93)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:131)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:518)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeSetAndReturn(MethodProperty.java:107)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BuilderBasedDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BuilderBasedDeserializer.java:255)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BuilderBasedDeserializer.deserialize(BuilderBasedDeserializer.java:145)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3736)",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2726)",
"com.amazon.ask.util.JacksonSerializer.deserialize(JacksonSerializer.java:69)",
"com.andrewtech.alexaskills.MagicDiceHandler.handleRequest(MagicDiceHandler.java:33)",
"sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
"sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)",
"sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)",
"java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
 ]
}
```

Its weird that my java code errors, but my test returns this...
https://gyazo.com/975bd574e090be351c53cb7d65a89d84

```
{"version":"1.0","userAgent":"ask-java/2.5.5 Java/1.8.0_181","response":{"outputSpeech":{"type":"SSML","ssml":"<speak>Number is 10</speak>"}}}
```

I can't seem to find out why the error is happening. Should be an error when Im compiling, but I cant seem to figure out exactly what... My dependencies are maven based if that helps.

My code: https://github.com/Realmm/MagicDiceGitHub/tree/master/MagicDice

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, turns out the error wasnt actually happening at all... lol. I just didnt press X on the red box when it initially came up before I fixed it, making me think it was coming up each time I submitted a new jar file